# Name for basic binary mathematic operators in C++

Tags: c++

Is there a simple way to fill in the comments in the code below to make this work?

```
// Assuming the following definitions already...
T a, b;
bool add, increase;

// ...can we fill in the comments here so result is computed as desired?
auto op = add ? (increase ? /* plus */ : /* minus */)
              : (increase ? /* times */ : /* divide */);

T result = op(a, b);
```

If it makes it easier, you may replace `T` with `float`.

---

I know we can get close by using `std::plus` (et al.), but that is a struct not a function, so it doesn't quite work to my knowledge.

Comment: @n.m. Oops forgot about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using F = std::function<float(float, float)>;
auto op = add ? (increase ? F(std::plus<float>()) : F(std::minus<float>()) )
          : (increase ? F(std::multiplies<float>()) : F(std::divides<float>()) );
```

Here, one of the standard function objects is constructed. However, since they all have different types, we must explicitely cast them to a common type - `std::function<float(float, float)>`.

Comment: I think this is the simplest and clearest solution so far. +1 to you!

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas maybe?

```
auto op = add ? (increase ? [](float a, float b) {return a+b;} : [](float a, float b) {return a-b;})
          : (increase ? [](float a, float b) {return a*b;} : [](float a, float b) {return a/b;});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe shorter, arguably more readable code might be of interest

```
return add ? (increase ? a+b : a-b)
          : (increase ? a*b : a/b);
```

If you need to store a callable object for later use, wrap it in a single lambda

```
auto fun = [=](T a, T b) { return add ? (increase ? a+b : a-b)
          : (increase ? a*b : a/b); };
```

Comment: This is, of course, more readable, but not what the OP asked for. They may need to store `op` for future use.

Comment: @Eugene that usage is not shown in the example. If it's needed, one can wrap the expression in a lambda (as opposed to wrapping four lambdas or fun.objs in an expression).

Comment: This inserts the conditions inside the lambda, which may be important if it is called many times.

Comment: The real example in which I will use it is much more complicated, and storing the op is much simpler than this.  One obvious disadvantage here is the repetition of `a` and `b` throughout the code, even though every expression is of the form `binary_operation(a, b)`.

Comment: @Apollys it's up to you to decide, but IMHO repeating `a` and `b` is much less obtrusive than repeating `std::...<float>()`, not speaking of repeating lambdas.

Comment: If `a` and `b` are replaced with real variable names, the former is most likely significantly longer (also we should be very used to seeing `std::` in our code, so the template parameter is the only real burden here I think). I agree the lambdas get burdensome quickly.

Comment: @Apollys Real variable names like what for instance? What kind of meaningful quantities you have that may be either added or multiplied based on some run time criteria? I am genuinely curious. Can you show an example from real code?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot give the real code, however, I think it would be okay for me to say that in general if you have some GUI in which a user may press some buttons to translate an object and some other buttons to scale the object, you may find the use for something like this naturally arises (depending on the details of the code organization of course).

Answer (score 1):

If only following comments can be changed:

```
auto op = add ? (increase ? /* plus */ : /* minus */)
              : (increase ? /* times */ : /* divide */);
```

You might use lambda decaying to function pointer with `+` or `*`:

```
auto op = add ? (increase ? +[](const T& lhs, const T& rhs) { return lhs + rhs; }
                          : +[](const T& lhs, const T& rhs) { return lhs - rhs; })
              : (increase ? +[](const T& lhs, const T& rhs) { return lhs * rhs; }
                          : +[](const T& lhs, const T& rhs) { return lhs / rhs; });
```

Comment: Note that, even though standard,  the decay does not work in visual  c++ targeting win32 because of  multiple calling conventions.

Comment: @Eugene: as we use `auto` without specifying calling convention we should be fine even with MSVC (I expect all lambda to decay to same calling convention). Else you can still be explicit about the conversion `static_cast<T (*)(const T&, const T&)>(lambda)`.

Comment: I appreciate you really sticking to the question directly.  My ultimate goal is simplicity and readability, which is of course subjective, but I think adding a line of code beforehand as in Eugene's answer is also fine.

Comment: Is the `+` actually necessary/helpful for this example? I was able to compile and run without it.  Side note: you missed the semicolons inside the lambdas, but I can't edit to fix 4 characters.

Comment: @Apollys: Feel free to edit for typos. Poster has notification about the edit and can still revert if needed. Fixed BTW.

Comment: The (stupid) minimum 6 character edit rule blocked me from editing.

Comment: Indeed the decays seems to happens without the trick.But I found it more explicit. Each lambda as its own type, and it seems not trivial to have as common type the decays of both.